# Attempting to make Webpack 3 compatible with IE8

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-2, defineproperty

Due to some legacy products that require IE8 compatibility mode we must not use `Object.defineProperty` calls.

We are building a single large bundle from TypeScript modules using ES6 syntax. If that matters, we're not utilizing live module loading, hot reloading, dynamic module loading and any similar technique.

I'm aware of the official limitation and the discussion here [in this thread](http://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3070). I'm trying to apply a not too nice fix/workaround as follows.

I've examined the bundle created by Webpack and as far as I can see that the only place this is used is when code accesses the `default` exported members.

I've technically changed the code to remove the `defineProperty` and use a simple "one-time" field assignment like this.

```
__webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
  if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
    exports[name] = getter();
    //Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
    //  configurable: false,
    //  enumerable: true,
    //  get: getter
    //});
  }
};
```

At first glance everything works just fine. But as I'm not a Webpack and ES6 modules spec expert, I'd like to ask what exactly the impact of this change can be? Is this a safe thing to do in this specific context?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3070

Comment: Thank you @DanielA.White, I've met this issue several times, what I ask here is if my "solution" to this issue makes sense in my context, because I cannot completely see the technical impacts.

Comment: It won’t dynamically update the value

Comment: That's clear, but I ment in what higher-level use-cases does it play any role?